# Slow Google Charts control: Possible causes?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-visualization

I have created a Google Charts linechart with a scrolling control, but the redraw performance is abysmal when I try to use the control. It literally locks up, moving fractionally when I try to scroll the horizontal scroller.

It wouldn't be the amount of data, I wouldn't think, as it is just two columns in JSON -- date and a measurement -- and only one year worth of daily data.

What am I missing? What could be causing this to be slow when I attempt to manipulate the linechart using a ChartRangeFilter?

Here is a subset of the code, just the Javascript for data loading and manipulation:

```
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartRangeFilter);

    function drawChartRangeFilter() {

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('chartRangeFilter_dashboard_div'));

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'chartRangeFilter_control_div',
      'options': {
        // Filter by the date axis.
        'filterColumnIndex': 0,
        'ui': {
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'chartOptions': {
            'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
            'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
          },
        }
      },
      // Initial range

      'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2015, 5, 6), 'end': new Date()}}
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'LineChart',
      'containerId': 'chartRangeFilter_chart_div',
      'options': {
        // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
        'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
        'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
        //'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 2000}},
        'legend': {'position': 'none'}
      },
      // Convert the first column from 'date' to 'string'.
      'view': {
        'columns': [
          {
            'calc': function(dataTable, rowIndex) {
              return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, 0);
            },
            'type': 'string'
          }, 1]
      }
    });

     var data2 = $.ajax({
                 url: "the url",
                 dataType: "JSON",
                 async: false,
                 }).responseText;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($.parseJSON(data2));

    dashboard.bind(control, chart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
  }
```

Comment: i noticed this control was slow on another question as well. wonder if the `'current'` version has problems, maybe try using a previous version, such as `'45'` or `'44'`??

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that, and went back & tested 43, 44, and 45, but no performance change. Darn.